# SQL Server - Copying data between tables where the Servers cannot be connected

Tags: sql, sql-server

We want some of our customers to be able to export some data into a file and then we have a job that imports that into a blank copy of a database at our location. Note: a DBA would not be involved. This would be a function within our application.

We can ignore table schema differences - they will match. We have different tables to deal with.

So on the customer side the function would ran somethiug like:

```
insert into myspecialstoragetable select * from source_table
insert into myspecialstoragetable select * from source_table_2
insert into myspecialstoragetable select * from source_table_3
```

I then run a `select * from myspecialstoragetable` and get a `.sql` file they can then ship to me which we can then use some `job/sql` script to import into our copy of the db.

I'm thinking we can use XML somehow, but I'm a little lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the bulk copy utility [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility)?  You can wrap it with your own program to make it easier for less sophisticated users.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a function within your application, in what language is the application front-end written ? If it is .NET, you can use Data Transformation Services in SQL Server to do a sample export. In the last step, you could save the steps into a VB/.NET module. If necessary, modify this file to change table names etc. Integrate this DTS module into your application. While doing the sample export, export it to a suitable format such as .CSV, .Excel etc, whichever format from which you will be able to import into a blank database.

Every time the user wants do an export, he will have to click on a button that would invoke the DTS module integrated into your application, that will dump the data to the desired format. He can mail such file to you.

If your application is not written in .NET, in whichever language it is written, it will have options to read data from SQL Server and dump them to a .CSV or text file with delimiters. If it is a primitive language, you may have to do it by concatenating the fields of every record, by looping through the records and writing to a file.

XML would be too far-fetched for this, though it's not impossible. At your end, you should have the ability to parse the XML file and import it into your location. Also, XML is not really suited if the no. of records are too large.

You probably think of a .sql file, as in MySql. In SQL Server, .sql files, that are generated by the 'Generate Scripts' function of SQL Server's interface, are used for table structures/DDL rather than the generation of the insert statements for each of the record's hard values.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I suggest _not_ using DTS (maybe you mean SSIS) as you'll need to include all the runtime, licencing etc. and that complicates things considerably. Also, to clarify, you can indeed fill a .SQL file (any file in fact) with INSERT statements which indeed insert hard values.

Comment: I meant the .sql files generated by the Generate Scripts menu item of SQL Server's interface. Edited the answer to clarify the same, based on your comment.